# What is the best way to handle uploaded images in Django Rest Framework on production server and how to do it?

Tags: django, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I'm relatively new to DRF, and I'm facing a problem where I have to set up many (thousands) of profile images. I need to do it "properly", so I guess uploading raw photos to the server is not the best way to do it. What service/ approach should I use?